# how would one go about finding specific words in a text file in c++

Tags: c++, text

how would i do this:

Got a text file called directorycontents.txt in this directorycontents.txt there is a bunch of text each one is a filename with a filename extension i want to be able to go like this if there is a filename extension of specific characters like .txt or .png then do fprintf(stderr,"whateva");

i have looked at istream and fstream and iostream but im not really shore how to use fstream to do this

thanks

Comment: You will need to `open` it `read` the contents and `search` for the keywords you are looking for.

Comment: what things must i look for to do that?

Comment: Actually read a good Book and read more in to [Input/Output Handling](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: Can you give an example? The part with '.png .bat' confused me?

Comment: got a text file called directorycontents.txt in this directorycontents.txt there is a bunch of text each one is a filename with a filename extension i want to be able to go like this if there is a filename extension of specific characters like .txt or .png then do this :)

Comment: Does it really have to be C++? Did you consider scripting languages?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'll just point you to the right direction and I won't post any code, as you need to try it by yourself.

First of all, read about reading files in C++. You can google it and there are tons of information about this. You can try with "how to read text file in C++", for example.

Second, prefer using [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/) and/or [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) - this is the C++ way to do it.

Then parse the file - you can read it word by word (using [istream::operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) ) , line by line (for example with [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) ) into [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) (as you're talking about file names).

And then analize the input - analize the parsed file and search for specific words in it - for example, `std::string` has member functions like [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) - I think this will be enough for your problem :)

I hope that helps. Just note, that we don't write code here, we just help finding solutions for problems.

Comment: i need code thats my problem i dont know how to read the documentation and redo what there asking without it not working or being weird and strange and i hate having to really think about how to do it when it should be there infront of my face for me too understand it and explained well

Comment: Very polite and instructive answer. +1

Comment: @NoobScratcher: If you "dont know how to read" then maybe you should try to learn this first. ;-)

Comment: No one will solve your problem for you. And no one will write code for you here. Get a book or ask somewhere else. If you post (in other question) some code, that you have tried to write, we can help. Otherwise - not.

Comment: thats the problem i dont want to do all that for one function and for every other function that will come after that its more effort and i hate bad emotions

Comment: @NoobScratcher - you're on the wrong place, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this definitely take a look at `std::fstreams`. Based on your vague description of what you're trying to do, you can use this simple program as a starting point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void doSomething();
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc < 2)
  {
    cout << "Usage: findsomething [filename]" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  ifstream infile(argv[1], ifstream::in);
  if(!infile.is_open())
  {
    cout << "Couldn't open file " << argv[1] << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  string line;
  while(getline(infile, line))
  {
    if(line.find(".txt") != string::npos ||
       line.find(".png") != string::npos ||
       line.find(".bat") != string::npos)
    {
      doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully, that's enough code to get you started and it isn't too difficult for you to read.